# Finding elements in array with binary search

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Trying to use `Arrays.binarySearch()` to search for a string in an array and return the index. However each time I call `Arrays.binarySearch()` I get the following exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Unknown Source)
at project.ArrayDirectory.lookupNumber(ArrayDirectory.java:97)
at project.test.main(test.java:12)
```

Here is my `ArrayDirectory class` -

```
    public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {

static Entry[] directory = new Entry[50];

@Override
public void addEntry(String surname, String initials, int extension) {

    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) { // counting number of
                                                    // entries in array
        if (directory[i] != null) {
            n++;
        }

    }

    if (n == directory.length) {
        Entry[] temp = new Entry[directory.length * 2]; // if array is full
                                                        // double the
                                                        // length.

        for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++)
            temp[i] = directory[i];
        directory = temp;
    }

    int position = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {

        position = i;

        if (directory[i] != null) { // sorting the array into alphabetical
                                    // order by surname.

            int y = directory[i].getSurname().compareTo(surname);
            if (y > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        else if (directory[i] == null) {
            break;
        }

    }

    System.arraycopy(directory, position, directory, position + 1,
            directory.length - position - 1);

    directory[position] = new Entry(initials, surname, extension); // placing
                                                                    // new
                                                                    // entry
                                                                    // in
                                                                    // correct
                                                                    // position.

}

@Override
public int lookupNumber(String surname, String initials) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Entry lookup = new Entry(surname, initials);
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(directory, lookup);
    return index;
}
```

}
Any ideas how I use binary search to find the correct index?

Thank you for you help.

edit -

I have also overridden `comapreTo`in my `Entry` class -

```
public int compareTo(Entry other) {
    return this.surname.compareTo(other.getSurname());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your invocation of

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(directory,lookup);
```

`directory` seems to contain only `null` elements. Check that you are initializing elements correctly.

Comment: After reviewing my test class, I realized I had not correctly initialized my `Entry` objects correctly. When I corrected this it initially seemed to solve my problem, but after further testing when I make multiple calls of `lookupNumber(surname,initials)` I get the same exception again. Any ideas as to what I am doing incorrectly? Thank you

Comment: @Nick Either directory or its elements are null. Nothing else in those lines could causecan NPE. Try logging what their values are before using them.

Answer (score 0):

I note two things:

```
static Entry [] directory = new Entry [1];
```

First, that code allocates space for one Entry in the array. It doesn't actually instantiate an Entry. That is, `directory[0]` is `null`. Secondly, a binary-search on an array with one entry is *crazy*. There is only one element. It must be `directory[0]`. Finally, you should sort your array to do a binary search on it.

Comment: just noticed that, sorry that is a mistake array should be set to a bigger length like 50 or so, was testing doubling the size of the array before.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept behind a binary search is the recursion of the following steps(Note the search assumes the list or array of elements is sorted in some form and the element exists there.):

1. Go to the middle element of the array.
2. check if the searched element is equal to the element at the middle. If it is then return its index.
3. if not then check if the searched element is 'smaller' or 'larger' than the element in the middle.
4. if it is smaller then go to step 1 using only the lower/first half of the array instead of the whole.
5. else go to step 1 using only the upper/last half of the array instead of the whole.

As the array is continuously divided in 2 it will eventually reach the size of 1 giving the result.

Now, suppose you are looking for an integer in an int array. Here is what the code would be like:

```
public static int binarySearch(int number, int[] array)
{
    boolean isHere = false;
    Integer index =0;

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == number)
        {
            isHere = true;
            i = array.length;
        }
    }
    if(!isHere)
    {
        index = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int arrayStart = 0;
        int arrayEnd = array.length;
         index = binarySearch(number, arrayStart, arrayEnd, array);
    }

    return index;
}


private static int binarySearch(int number, int start, int end, int[] array)
{
    // this formula ensures the index number will be preserved even if 
           // the array is divided later.
    int middle = (start+ end)/ 2;

    if(array[middle] == number)
    {
        return middle;
    }
    else
    {
        if(number < array[middle])
        {
            //searches the first half of the array
        return binarySearch(number, start, middle, array);
        }
        else
        {
            // searches the last half of the array
            return binarySearch(number, middle, end, array);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the compareTo() method instead of <,>, & == operators in your example. The logic should still be the same.